# Run a Batch Script at Windows Shutdown using GPedit.msc from CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, boot, script, batch-file

I would like to run a Batch Script at Windows 10 Shutdown by using Command Prompt. I know it's not easy.

All I know about GPedit.msc is that when you set a Shutdown Script it creates these regedit entries:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\0]    
"GPO-ID"="LocalGPO"    
"SOM-ID"="Local"    
"FileSysPath"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\GroupPolicy\\Machine"    
"DisplayName"="Stratégie de groupe locale"    
"GPOName"="Stratégie de groupe locale"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\0\0]    
"Script"="C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"    
"Parameters"="/C "C:\BATCH_FILE.bat""    
"ExecTime"=hex(b):00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

( These entries are the same for Startup, just changes Shutdown for Startup. )

( I saw that in some forums say that in the following regedit entry Gpedit also creates Script entries: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System` 
but it does not, at least not in Windows 10. )

( To run a Batch Script at LogOFF it's neccessary to use `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` as the Script Name and `/C C:\path\to\batch\script.bat` as the Script Parameters. )

And also creates a `Script.ini` file in the following directory:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts
```

So knowing all this I exported those regedit entries into a .reg file, and copied Script.ini; I deleted the entry from GPedit.msc and tried to set the Script manually by starting the .reg file and copying again the script.ini file into its directory (all of this can be easily done by CMD), but it did not work.
GPedit.msc shows the LogOFF entry but it only works if I press edit and apply...

I also tried to update GPedit by using the command `gpupdate /force` after setting the script manually but nothing happen.

I think that I'm so close to solve this...

Comment: Why would you want this, and not use gpedit.msc? Also, you can use Task Scheduler to start a program/script at startup or shutdown. schtasks.exe can be used from the commandline to create a task, or even simpler: first export a task, and then import it.

Comment: @LPChip Because I'm trying to develop my first CMD program and I want to run a quick task on Windows Shutdown if it's possible. Task Scheduler it's not what I want, but thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Task Scheduler is what you should be using.  Don’t try to reinvent the wheel poorly.

Comment: As previously mention the path to least resistance is to use Windows Task Scheduler and use the [OnEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27327480/1417694) option.